# Very corrupted Python 3.9.13

Tags: python, windows-10, uninstallation, python-3.9, corruption

I don't know how I did this but Python is completely broken, trying to run it from the command line results in "The code execution cannot proceed because python39.dll was not found. Reinstalling the program may fix this problem."

I logically tried to reinstall but I can't, trying to uninstall says fatal error and trying to repair gives "Error writing to file: C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSobeareFoundation.Mhon.3.9_3.9.3568.0_ x64_qsznZkfra8p0\python39.dll. Verify that you have access to that directory."

I made it to the folder and the dll is missing, I found a copy online but I can't move it into the folder because "I don't have permission" even though the security tab says I should have full access to the folder.

Comment: I think your disk may be going bad. That should be `PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python`...

Comment: You should not put dlls found online manually. Try installing another python version from scratch. eg: python 3.8 and see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a solution, I moved the "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSobeareFoundation.Mhon.3.9_3.9.3568.0_ x64_qsznZkfra8p0" folder to my desktop and then ran repair again

Comment: Rather than a solution I'd consider this a temporal hack. I'd still rather completely uninstall python and install it again from zero.

Comment: yeah it wasn't working after that but then I was able to fully reinstall and fix the issue